# Error Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, xpath, visual-studio-2017

The following is my code in Visual studio 2017:

```
   private String generateXPATH(IWebElement childElement, String current)
            {
                String childTag = childElement.TagName;
                if (childTag.Equals("html"))
                {
                    return "/html[1]" + current;
                }
                IWebElement parentElement = childElement.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));
                List<IWebElement> childrenElements = parentElement.FindElements(By.XPath(" ../"));
                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < childrenElements.Count; i++)
                {
                    IWebElement childrenElement = childrenElements[i];
                    String childrenElementTag = childrenElement.TagName;
                    if (childTag.Equals(childrenElementTag))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (childElement.Equals(childrenElement))
                    {
                        return generateXPATH(parentElement, "/" + childTag + "[" + count + "]" + current);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

At line

```
List<IWebElement> childrenElements = parentElement.FindElements(By.XPath(" ../"));
```

I get the following error:

> "Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List' ".

How can I fix this?

Comment: Change the List<IWebElement> to ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>. This is the return value of the FindElements method.

Answer (score 1):

The types don't match - as the error says.

You have:

```
List<IWebElement> childrenElements = parentElement.FindElements(By.XPath(" ../"));
```

and the error says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' ".

So, change the type of your `childrenElements` to a `ReadOnlyCollection`:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> childrenElements = parentElement.FindElements(By.XPath(" ../"));
```

Answer (score 0):

A List is not equivalent to a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` so you will either have to use something like

```
IEnumerable<IWebElement> childElements = parentElement.FindElements(By.XPath(" ../"));
```

or use `var` to use type inference, or `.ToList()` to get you the list you want to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assing `ReadOnlyCollection` to your `List` variable. So there are multple ways how to fix that. Either you can make your `childrenElements` a type `var`, so c# will choose the type of that variable for you. But I would not recommend this type of solution. Or you can add a `.ToList()` at the end of that broblematic line so it will look like this:

```
List<IWebElement> childrenElements = parentElement.FindElements(By.XPath(" ../")).ToList<IWebElement>();
```

Is it clear?